# Play videos from Azure Media Service offline in Angular

Tags: angular, azure, progressive-web-apps, plyr, azure-media-services

I'm currently developing an Angular application in which you can watch some videos.
The videos get streamed over HLS from an Azure Media Service. So they are encoded for adaptive streaming.
For the player I'm using [Plyr](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr).

Now I want to be able to watch these videos when I'm offline. So first I'm turning my application into an PWA.

But then, how can I download videos from an Azure Media Service and play them within Plyr?

Answer (score 1):

I havent working with media services but I assume [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-deliver-asset-download) will help

You would need to have backend which will create you temporary link to download, then you can download and save on client side

Answer (score 1):

You can get a SAS URL to the container that hosts the Assets video files. If you encoded in Azure Media Services, you will find a collection of MP4 files with different bitrates and resolutions in that folder.  You can just use the storage API to get a SAS URL and just download it.

See the samples here for .NET which shows how to encode and download in .NET
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet/blob/main/VideoEncoding/Encoding_H264/Program.cs

You can look at the lines in DownloadResults to see how to get a SAS token URL - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet/blob/a611f5559d7c907a8618e0525df57e1577532f17/VideoEncoding/Encoding_H264/Program.cs#L573