# what folder can I put large video for angular in?

Tags: angular, streaming

I thought that the Angular "assets" folder was used to put in used images or videos, but in case the file exceeds 2gb I can't put it inside.

so how do you handle large videos in this case?

*(possibly misplaced question)* how do streaming sites handle this?
My goal was to create one to train me in angular programming

Comment: p.s.: I tried to put the file in a simple folder on the PC by copying the path, but it gave me access error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually large files of binary data like videos, images, etc. are stored in some sort of service like Azure BlobStorage or AWS's S3 buckets. Then what you do is you consume their API based on their documentation.

What your backend will do is store an ID reference to that file in said storage location, it might also respond with some sort of SAS token your front end can consume instead of storing the connection string credentials in the front end as that can be easily figured out and open you up for a world of no good, very bad pain.

Some references: [Play videos from Azure Media Service offline in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67581931/play-videos-from-azure-media-service-offline-in-angular)

https://code-maze.com/azure-blob-storage-with-asp-net-core-and-angular/

note that in these examples their backend (that is server) code is in C# since that is Microsoft's flagship language